# Interaction between forms

Tags: winforms, forms, function, visual-studio-2012, interaction

I am using visual studio 2012 (windows form application) and I have two forms, one with a label and the other with a button. I want it so that when you click the button the label on the other form goes up by one. I already have:

```
Label1 = Label1 + 1
```

I just need to know how to make the connection with the two forms. Maybe call a function?
Btw I am new to the program and script so in simple terms plz.

Comment: Maybe simply try it by yourself? Or use the search function?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a sample I create for you. Add Fomr2 Like this:

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1.Instance.Controls.Find("label1", true).First().Text = "Some thing";
    }
}
```

And Form1:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Instance = this;
    }

    private static Form1 _Instance;
    public static Form1 Instance
    {
        get { return _Instance; }
        set { Instance = value; }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        new Form2().Show();
    }
```

Comment: @UweKeim The variable can be any of the controls also. this code just can be a starting of a better idea!

Comment: I think the point @UweKeim is trying to make is that this is horrible practice, and isn't the start of anything but bad habits and worthless code.  An example such as this is not helpful.